# LatexIndent: Inside commands mandatory arguments line breaks at a \\ and column limit

Tags: formatting, captions, latexindent

I have tried to configure `latexindent` to format my captions such that they don't surpass 80 characters and have a line break after a double backslash. My exploration wasn't fruitful.
This is in my `config.yaml` for `latexindent`:

```yaml
lookForAlignDelims:
    caption: 1
modifyLineBreaks:
    mandatoryArguments:
        caption:
            DBSFinishesWithLineBreak: 1
            MandArgBodyStartsOnOwnLine: 1
            RCuBStartsOnOwnLine: 1
    textWrapOptions:
        columns: 80
        multipleSpacesToSingle: 1
        blocksFollow:
            other: '\\\]|\\item(?:\h|\[)|\\caption(?:\h|\[)'      # regex
        # blocksBeginWith:
        #     other: '\\begin(.*)\\caption|\\caption'
```

I was able to bring it to break lines at `\\` and that they never surpass 80 columns and this is the output:

```tex
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width = 0.8\textwidth]{./figures/digz.png}
    \end{center}
    \caption[Aufbau des Digitalzähler]{
        Aufbau des Digitalzähler           \\
        1 \(\dots\) Halterung
        für radioaktive Quelle             \\
        2 \(\dots\) Zählrohr               \\
        3 \(\dots\) Halterung um
        später das Aluminium zu Befestigen \\
        4 \(\dots\) Digitalzähler          \\
        5 \(\dots\)
        Optische Bank um den Abstand zu variieren
    }\label{fig:digz}
\end{figure}
```

The desired output is:

```tex
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width = 0.8\textwidth]{./figures/digz.png}
    \end{center}
    \caption[Aufbau des Digitalzähler]{
        Aufbau des Digitalzähler                                    \\
        1 \(\dots\) Halterung für radioaktive Quelle                \\
        2 \(\dots\) Zählrohr                                        \\
        3 \(\dots\) Halterung um später das Aluminium zu Befestigen \\
        4 \(\dots\) Digitalzähler                                   \\
        5 \(\dots\) Optische Bank um den Abstand zu variieren
    }\label{fig:digz}
\end{figure}
```

Any suggestion how to fix this, it seems like these two options dont play nicely with eachother.

EDIT:
Another example would be:

```tex
    \caption[Erhaltene Zählraten bei $\beta$-Strahlung bei verschiedenen Dicken] {
        Erhaltene
        Zählraten bei $\beta$-Strahlung bei verschiedenen Dicken einer Aluminiumplatte
        bei einer Torzeit von \SI{10}{\second}. Dabei sind die Zählraten exakte Werte. \\
        \(D \dots\) Dicke der Aluminiumabschirmung in $\mu$m mit einer Unsicherheit von
        \SI{1}{\percent}                                                               \\
        \(z_{i} \dots\) erhaltene Zählrate bei entsprechendem
        Abstand
    } \label{tab:alu}
```

expected:

```tex
    \caption[Erhaltene Zählraten bei $\beta$-Strahlung bei verschiedenen Dicken] {
        Erhaltene Zählraten bei $\beta$-Strahlung bei verschiedenen Dicken einer 
        Aluminiumplatte bei einer Torzeit von \SI{10}{\second}. Dabei sind die 
        Zählraten exakte Werte.                                    \\
        \(D \dots\) Dicke der Aluminiumabschirmung in $\mu$m mit einer Unsicherheit 
        von \SI{1}{\percent}                                      \\
        \(z_{i} \dots\) erhaltene Zählrate bei entsprechendem Abstand
    } \label{tab:alu}
```

Comment: can you try `other: '\\\\|\\\]|\\item(?:\h|\[)|\\caption(?:\h|\[)' `  I can't test it at the moment, but can look a it later if that doesn't help...

Comment: this works in the sense that it doesn't create the weird line breaks, however it doesn't produce a line break at 80 char then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### solution

```yaml
lookForAlignDelims:
    caption: 1
modifyLineBreaks:
    mandatoryArguments:
        caption:
            DBSFinishesWithLineBreak: 1
            MandArgBodyStartsOnOwnLine: 1
            RCuBStartsOnOwnLine: 1
    textWrapOptions:
        columns: 80
        multipleSpacesToSingle: 1
        blocksFollow:
            other: \\\\|\\\]|\\item(?:\h|\[)|\\caption(?:\h|\[)# <!-- new bit
            #      ^^^^  <---- new bit
        blocksBeginWith:
            0-9: 1
            other: \\\(
            #      ^^^^  <---- new bit
```

gives

```tex
\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width = 0.8\textwidth]{./figures/digz.png}
 \end{center}
 \caption[Aufbau des Digitalzähler]{
  Aufbau des Digitalzähler                                    \\
  1 \(\dots\) Halterung für radioaktive Quelle                \\
  2 \(\dots\) Zählrohr                                        \\
  3 \(\dots\) Halterung um später das Aluminium zu Befestigen \\
  4 \(\dots\) Digitalzähler                                   \\
  5 \(\dots\) Optische Bank um den Abstand zu variieren
 }\label{fig:digz}
\end{figure}

\caption[Erhaltene Zählraten bei $\beta$-Strahlung bei verschiedenen Dicken] {
 Erhaltene
 Zählraten bei $\beta$-Strahlung bei verschiedenen Dicken einer Aluminiumplatte
 bei einer Torzeit von \SI{10}{\second}. Dabei sind die Zählraten exakte Werte. \\
 \(D \dots\) Dicke der Aluminiumabschirmung in $\mu$m mit einer Unsicherheit von
 \SI{1}{\percent}                                                               \\
 \(z_{i} \dots\) erhaltene Zählrate bei entsprechendem Abstand
} \label{tab:alu}
```

### explanation

- We need to tell `latexindent.pl` to allow text wrap blocks to *begin* with `[0-9]` as detailed in https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-the-m-switch.html#lst-tw-0-9
- We need to tell `latexindent.pl` to allow text wrap blocks to *begin* with `\(` which is like the example at https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-the-m-switch.html#lst-tw-bb-announce-yaml
- We also need to tell `latexindent.pl` to allow text wrap blocks to *follow* `\\` as detailed in https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-the-m-switch.html#text-wrap-blocksfollow-examples

Comment: Sadly this doesn't solve it consitently. I added another example in the description.

Comment: Updated @xyhlon

Comment: thx this works now most of the tim

Comment: It works for the example you posted :)